# Accepted for Masters, Is It Rude To Ask About Scholarships?

Tags: masters, funding, international-students

First things first: I'm not a native American, and I was accepted for my masters at an American college. So far, I still need to send some documentation before the official offer is made.

On their website, it is stated that accepted students are eligible for a scholarship. So, is it rude, while I'm still sending and solving the documents, to ask how can I obtain the scholarship mentioned?

Comment: It's not rude, you could try. The university will make a decision.

Comment: It's not rude, and the only way you'll find out more is by asking; learning to ask good questions is an important part of graduate study.  Just ask for instructions and requirements for applying for the scholarship.  Good luck with the scholarship!

Comment: @aparente001 thank! I will reply informing the documents are on the way (since it takes a while shipping from different countries) and asking how can I proceed to obtain the scholarship. For some reason I cant tag Student T

Comment: @StudentT - Myrium is trying to tag you, not sure what for....

Comment: More precisely, ask you you can *apply for* the scholarship, not how you can obtain it.

Comment: Just so you know, the term "[native American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States)" usually refers to the indigenous people of the land which is now the United States, and sometimes more broadly the Americas.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not rude to ask about scholarships! Some are easy to get, while others have stringent requirements, so it might be more appropriate to ask "what scholarships am I eligible for" or "what scholarships can I apply for" instead of "what scholarships can I get."

---

A tip about word usage: If you're doing a masters degree than you're almost definitely attending a "university" rather than a "college." In the US, a college refers to an administrative unit that awards undergraduate degrees. The term "school" is also used to refer to degree-granting units that award any kinds of degrees. A university is a collection of schools. For example, Harvard University contains a college and several other schools as can be seen [here](http://www.harvard.edu/schools). Some universities (especially larger ones) have multiple colleges, generally separating Engineering from Arts and Sciences. If you tell someone in the US that you're attending college, they will almost certainly assume that you're an undergraduate. "Attending university" or "attending graduate school" are the common things to say.

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightenment! At first, I considered it like it were synonyms.

Comment: @Myrium The words (or their cognates) tend to have wildly varying usages in different countries from what I've gathered. A further point of clarification: some larger universities contain multiple colleges (often dividing "the college of engineering" from "the college of arts and sciences.") Some institutions are named with those words in the name, e.g., "Boston University" and "Boston College," which I think used to correspond to who had grad depts and who only did undergraduate work, but now everyone has graduate programs. So Boston College is a university and contains a college